# How can the dot product between unit vector and random data become a mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to reproduce a result from the [TensorFlow research library](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deep_contextual_bandits), and in doing so I am having a difficult time understanding a few simple operations and how they relate.

The authors write:

> We created the Financial Dataset by pulling the stock prices of d = 21 publicly traded companies in NYSE and Nasdaq, for the last 14 years (n = 3713). For each day, the context was the price difference between the beginning and end of the session for each stock. We synthetically created the arms to be a linear combination of the contexts, representing k = 8 different potential portfolios.

In the code, they go through these steps:

```
    betas = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (context_dim, num_actions))
    betas /= np.linalg.norm(betas, axis=0)

    mean_rewards = np.dot(contexts, betas)
    noise = np.random.normal(scale=sigma, size=mean_rewards.shape)
    rewards = mean_rewards + noise
```

There are `N=21` stocks in the data. Index `i` denotes each of those `N` stocks. The timeseries for each stock runs for some period of time `t...T` where 14 years of data yields `T=3713` data points.

- `betas` is `21x8` (21 stocks, 8 actions).
- `contexts` is `3713x22` (3713 days, 21 stocks)
- `mean_rewards` becomes `3713x21` (1825 days, 8 actions)

The `betas` are samples from a uniform distribution with support `[-1, 1]` divided by their own L2 norm, so we get the unit norm.

The `mean_rewards` are the dot product between the contexts and the unit vector `betas`.

$$
MeanReward_{i} = Context_{i}\cdot\frac{beta_i}{||beta_i||_2} 
$$

The final reward is this quantity, with some added noise.

My questions are:

1) **How is the dot product between a random variable and a unit vector related to a mean**?

2) **How does this constitute a linear combination**?

Comment: What index $i$ "indexes" ? The individual stock? if so, is $beta_i$ the "usual" [stock's $\beta$](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/beta.asp) ?

Comment: The [dot product](https://mathinsight.org/dot_product) of a vector $C_i$ with unit vector $u_i$, denoted with $C_i \cdot u_i$, is defined to be the projection of $C_i$ in the direction of $u_i$, or the amount that $C_i$ is pointing in the same direction as unit vector $u_i$.

Comment: I have added some edits to explain the indexing. Also, I dont think `beta` here is related to $Beta$ in the finansial understanding as covariance/variance. It is simply draws from a uniform distribution, divided with its own norm.

Comment: Dividing $\beta_i$ by its norm means to "normalize" it, to transform it in a unit vector.